# why does displayed number goes above the input number in java?

Tags: java

Currently, I am doing an assignment on displaying all odd numbers up to a user inputted specific odd number. The requirement is to include the input number, however, I don't understand why does the code always goes to the next Odd number compared to what user inputted. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddNumbers {


public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Pls enter an odd number you want to finish to: ");
     int capp_number = input.nextInt();
     int startingNumber = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i < capp_number; i+= 2){
     startingNumber += 2;
     System.out.println(startingNumber);
     }
```

Comment: So, your loop will continue only while `i < capp_number`, so it will exclude `capp_number`. Maybe try `I <= capp_number` instead

Comment: Why do you use `i` and `startingNumber`? Just let `i` start at `1`, modify the `for`-condition to include the `capp_number` and print `i`.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You have assigned capp-number a function input.nextInt()  which keeps making a function call for each looping.  You should first assign it to a temp variable then make a reference to that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `i` starts at `0` (It is even), and you are checking to see if it is less than `capp_number` (which should be odd), and then adding two to `i`. `startingNumber` starts at `1`, so it is odd. So if the user enters 5 it will go like:

Iteration 1:

```
i (0) < 5 ? Yes:
print startingNumber+2
output: 3
i == 2
```

Iteration 2:

```
i (2) < 5 ? Yes:
print startingNumber +2
output: 5
i == 4
```

Iteration 3:

```
i (4) < 5 ? Yes:
print startingNumber +2
output: 7
i == 6
```

Iteration 4

```
i (6) < 5 No:
end loop
```

To fix this, start `i` at one:

```
for(int i = 1; i < capp_number; i+= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but why did you write this ?

```
while(startingNumber < capp_number);
```

i agree with a previous answer  and think that there is no reason for this line. And also you should correct your loop as it was also mentioned in previous answer:`for(int i = 0; i < capp_number; i+= 2)`

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to solve the problem and tried to add in a while statement to make sure that the for statement didn't go wrong. That is it.

Comment: ok , but usually it should be done like that: while(condition){for (){}}

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You needed to initialise `i` to `1` within the for-loop. `1` is an odd number so instead of starting with an even number (0), you look for every odd number.

For example, if you start at 1: 1+2=3, 3+2=5, 5+2=7.... and so on.

For example, if you start at 0: 0+2=2, 2+2=4, 4+2=6.... and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Pls enter an odd number you want to finish to: ");
 int capp_number = input.nextInt();
 int startingNumber = 1;

 for(int i = 1; i < capp_number; i += 2){
 startingNumber += 2;

 System.out.println(startingNumber);

 }
```